# how to access to the configuration of my raspberry pi os lite

Tags: pi-4, raspi-config, raspbian-lite, modules

Hello I want to access the menuconfig of the raspberry pi os lite, but I had this error

```
root@raspberrypi:/# make menuconfig 
make: *** No rule to make target 'menuconfig'.  Stop.
root@raspberrypi:/#
```

I want to see the configuration of this os is it possible ? or does and a config file exists? under which directory can I found something like that

actually I am working on creating an os with buildroot and the menuconfig is a litle bit scary for me so I wanted to check the configuration of the raspberry pi os lite to know which modules and dependencies are necessary. if anyone could help it would be great

Comment: `sudo modprobe configs; zcat /proc/config.gz > /tmp/kernel.config; cat /tmp/kernel.config`

Comment: You should really run `man make` and read that page.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I just read it, so I presume that the source code of this os and the Makefiles are not available on my sdcard but in the host machine where it was developed ? so doing a make menuconfig has no meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get the configuration of your Pi's kernel, and you plan to do development elsewhere, run `sudo modprobe configs; zcat /proc/config.gz > .config`, and then copy the `.config` file to your development folder.

If you plan to do development on the Pi, install the kernel source tree, e.g. with `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux`. This will create a folder called `linux` inside the current directory, and the Makefile you need to run `make menuconfig` will be inside that `linux` folder. You don't have to configure everything manually, there are `make bcmrpi_defconfig` / `make bcm2709_defconfig` / `make bcm2711_defconfig` commands which create a default kernel configuration for Pi1 / Pi 2 and 3 / Pi 4, respectively.

Make sure you have good Internet connection and several GB of free space on your SD card before you start, the kernel is quite a big project.

Also, read about `git`: if you want to explore different kernel configurations, you'll have to pick the right branch of the repository with `git checkout branch_name`. The default kernel branch seems to be `rpi-5.4.y` at the time of writing.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying ! but I am trying to create a specific kernel I am don't intend to work with the default configuration, actually I am a little bit lost I need to cross compile Qt on an os which has no desktop version no server x ...  it will be for an industrial project and will be implemented on raspberry pi 4 , In the beginning I tried to build a kernel following the official documentation of raspberry  and it didin't work for me I couldn't mount the image https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118498/building-kernel-for-raspberry-pi-4-b-on-a-host-machineubuntu-18-04

Comment: after that I worked on the raspberry pi os lite and cross compiled Qt.. it worked but not perfectly because with my configuration I couldn't enable eglfs for raspberry .. and know I am finding a way to create my os and configure it the right way to make qt work on it I am working with buildroot right now. I know it is possible to make it work on an os which has no x server https://qtcrosscompile.blogspot.com/2020/05/build-cross-compile-qt5.html and I am trying to do it ..

Comment: thank youu for your time I just want to clarify that I did it, and it was stupid to ask why the make menuconfig can't work, I just wanted to say that I wanted to find the configuration file ! I will edit the title of my question to make it more clear it may help someone

Answer (score 2):

To install the program you have to issue the command:

```
sudo apt install libncurses5-dev
```

Full kernel building instructions can be  found [on this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) as part of the RPF/RPT kernel documentation [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/)

Comment: I installed `libncurses5-dev` and still couldn't access the `menuconfig` I got the same error, I followed the kernel building instruction but it couldn't work for me https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118498/building-kernel-for-raspberry-pi-4-b-on-a-host-machineubuntu-18-04 so I gave up and worked with raspberry pi os lite but now I want to make my one microlinux os so I am working on buildroot